# Create StructuredSelection from Project in Headless Mode

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, headless

I need a possibility to create a `StructuredSelection` from the selected Project in a headless plugin in Eclipse.

The following code I have already:

```
IProject project = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getProject("NameOfProject");
```

But what now?
I can't access a method, that give me all files for example.StructuredSelection like the user is click on a project in GUI mode.

Normally, if the user click right on a project i get a ISelection from eclipse. This ISelection i convert to StructedSelection. Now i need a possibility to create this in a headless plugin.

Comment: Do you just want the IProject in the selection or something else?

Comment: I want to have a StructuredSelection within all files in project.
I want to create a headless plugin.
But i don't know the right way...

Answer (score 0):

To get a list of the top level members (files and folders) in an `IProject` call `IProject.members()` which returns an array of `IResource` objects. If you want to include entries in folders in the project go through the members list looking for `IContainer` objects and call `IContainer.members()`.

When you have your final array of `IFile` objects use `new StructuredSelection(files array)`.

Alternatively if you just want the `IProject` selected just do `new StructuredSelection(project)`

Comment: my plugin have to simulate a right click from the user.
Normally, if the user click right on a project i get a ISelection from eclipse. This ISelection i convert to StructedSelection.
Now i need a possibility to create this in a headless plugin.
Do you know, what i mean?

Comment: That would just be a selection containing the `IProject` - see edited answer.

Comment: Thank you.

If the user click right on the project i get UMLModelImpl objects in ISelection.
Do you know it's possible to get UMLModelImpl from IProject in headless mode?

Comment: UMLModelImpl is not part of base Eclipse. I guess you are using MDT which I don't know anything about

Comment: Okay, generally, it's possible to cast IProject to another Class?
I tried (UMLModelIml) project, but eclipse throw an CastClassException.